# How to put in a variable the result of an external pipe?

Tags: c, popen

This is my code (is a working in progress to calculate in GB the size of disk in a system)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
char line[128];
 FILE* file = popen("/usr/sbin/prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0 |/usr/local/bin/grep 'slice 0' -A 2|grep length|cut -d : -f 3|cut -d '(' -f 1|cut -c 2-1000", "w");
  printf("The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is %s \n",file);
  pclose(file);
  return 0;
  }
```

The output is very bad

```
The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is
41929587
```

I want

```
The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is 41929587
```

My idea is to store in a variable the output of popen pipe, but I don't know how to do: is possible?

EDIT1:

I have tried this line

```
  printf("The size in 512b blocks of the disk /dev/rdsk/c0b0t2d0s0del is %d \n",*file);
```

but return 0

Comment: You're not printing the size of anything. You're printing the address of the file pointer, which has nothing to do with the used space on the disk. I'd figure that part out first before you worry about anything else.

Comment: Yes I know, the line with printf is totally wrong, for this reason I ask how to put the result in a variable, with bash is easy a=`command|pipe` then `echo $a`

Comment: You could call  `fgets()` to read a line of output from the child process into a char-array, and then parse the characters in the char-array (using whatever logic is necessary to do so):  https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets  (be sure to pass `"r"` to the popen call's second argument rather than `"w"` though, so that you can read from the child process's stdout stream)

Comment: Why are you writing this in C?  Bash or failing that Python would be a more suitable choice.

Comment: I know how to do in bash, in this time I'm studying C

Comment: (you likely won't need the `2>&1` magic, just that topic shows how to read from a `popen()`-d "file")